# Laravel 5.4 beanstalkd multiple workers

Tags: laravel-5, beanstalkd

I have a million tasks in the queue that sends bulk sms. I am using the beanstalkd driver to as my queue driver. I have installed beanstalk and supervisord on my ubuntu machine.

In the docs - http://supervisord.org/configuration.html i found`numprocs=5` for instance. Does this create five workers?.

If i have two different workers, will i have 5 processes for each worker?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here the link to the Laravel 'config' regarding supervisord.

[Queues Supervisor Config](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#supervisor-configuration)

> In this example, the numprocs directive will instruct Supervisor to run 8 queue:work processes and monitor all of them, automatically restarting them if they fail.

Comment: is there guarantee that each job will be done by one worker if i spawn 8 processes?

Comment: Each process will check for jobs and just run them. If they are done they go to the next job.